# parsing json in android studio

Tags: java, android, json, django

I am developing first time in android and i have never used json data before. I will develop an application of event calendar of my university. We developed web version application in Django and we implement tastypie (restapi) so i need to use this json data for android mobile version. My json data is like this :

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 5
    },
    "objects": [{
        "Location": "Z011",
        "Notes": "asdf",
        "Title": "Literature Talking",
        "id": 3,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/Events/3/"
    }, {
        "Location": "BatÄ± KampÃ¼sÃ¼, Sinema Salonua",
        "Notes": "sd",
        "Title": "TARÄ°HÃ‡E KONFERANSLARI SERÄ°SÄ° 25",
        "id": 4,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/Events/4/"
    }, {
        "Location": "in Campus",
        "Notes": "afafdf",
        "Title": "Self-Assessment Project",
        "id": 5,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/Events/5/"
    }, {
        "Location": "KÃ¼tÃ¼phane",
        "Notes": "fs",
        "Title": "51.KÃ¼tÃ¼phane  HaftasÄ±",
        "id": 6,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/Events/6/"
    }]
}
```

how can I parse this Json data in android studio?

Comment: A good library to use is Google's own: Gson. Check that out!

Comment: Or you could start here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below code you will be able to get **Title** and  **Location**

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response);//This is response from webservice
    String totalCount = obj.getJSONObject("meta").getString("total_count"); //for getting total_count
    JSONArray json_array = obj.getJSONArray("objects");
    for(int j=0;j<json_array.length();j++) {
        String title = json_array.getJSONObject(j).getString("Title");
        String location= json_array.getJSONObject(j).getString("Location");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this website to help you view the Json structure better

http://www.jsontree.com/

What you have is a Json Object since it starts and ends with curly braces.

For example if I had a Json as `{"Id":"1"}`
The Key is "Id" and the value is "1"

A Json object can have a Json inside the value as well(Which is your case)

And example is `{"Id":{"Place1":"1", "Place2":"2"}}`

So the Key is `"Id"` and it has the value `"Place1":"1", "Place2":"2"`

So the value is also a Json.

It can get a little messy with Jsons in Jsons.

Here is a good tutorial on parsing Json

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm